Is this a valid Irish word?
In Irish, most consonants are divided into broad (velarized) and slender (palatalized) variants, and the orthography marks them with neighboring vowels, which are similarly divided. This gives rise to the caol le caol agus leathan le leathan (slender with slender and broad with broad) rule – a medial sequence of consonants must have the same class of vowel on either side: in leabhar, bh is surrounded by two broad vowels, so it is broad as well, and in cailín, l is surrounded by two slender vowels, so it is slender. a, o and u are broad and e and i are slender (similar with the vowels with the fada: á ó ú é í); ae (but not áe, aé, or áé) is also considered broad.
Given a word, output whether it follows this rule.
Input
You may assume that the input has only the following characters with their uppercase variants:
aábcdeéfghiílmnoóprstuú
AÁBCDEÉFGHIÍLMNOÓPRSTUÚ

Input will be given in the NFC normalization form.
Tests
Valid:
deartháireacha
madra
nuachtán
gaolta
ceannasaithe
snámhann
fómhair
laethanta
béar
Bealtaine
hAoine
ball
tree
ggg
laEthanta
agus
úsáideoir

Invalid:
codegolf
delta
alishanoi
ABI
anseo
breithlá
aéco
áeco
áéco

(Note that anseo and breithlá are Irish words, but they happen not to follow this rule. You should still output a falsy answer for them for the sake of simplicity.)

I think laethanta should be falsey because th is surrounded by e and a

@鳴神裁四点一号 Perhaps that is truthy because "ae is also considered broad"?

...if so @bb94 is áé considered broad?

I don’t think aé, áe, and áé are used in Irish at all. I’ll say that only ae should be.

I have assumed AE, Ae, and aE are classed as broad too hopefully, that's right. It's probably worth updating the text of the question for clarity about all of this too.

@bb94: "I don’t think aé, áe, and áé are used in Irish at all." If they're not used at all, then I would suggest you rule it as a Don't Care condition (TL;DR it's undefined behavior, nothing you do here is a wrong choice, whatever works for you) rather than mandating that they shouldn't be considered to be broad. (I'm aware that your comment leaves it somewhat ambiguous as to how you're ruling on this, but I'm pointing it out for clarification purposes)

ospidéal and osréalach are other valid Irish words that don't follow clcalll.

@Flater I’d say any word containing aé, áe or áé should return false by definition, since these sequences are categorically impossible in Irish. They have no defined value as tautosyllabic units and could only possibly appear across word boundaries in compounds – but when vowels coalesce in compounds, they should be separated by hyphens, so you’d end up with a-é, á-e and á-é (all of which are possible). The same is true of sequences like uo, eu, ie, au and various others. Irish spelling is complicated. :-)

@JanusBahsJacquet: ggg isn't an Irish word and that's listed as a "valid" Irish word in the examples. While the title refers to being a "valid Irish word", the purpose of the exercise solely focuses on the slender/broad division for its vowels. It's not asking to vet any other spelling, nor to check if the word itself exists in an Irish dictionary. We're only asked to apply the broad/slender rule. Non-existing words can still be judged for correctness on broad/slender. If your interpretation were correct then the valid examples would only contain actual Irish words, which is not the case.

@Flater True, there are lots of other spelling patterns that would be invalid but aren’t part of the exercise here.

Retina 0.8.2, 39 bytes
ae|[aáoóuú]
#@
[eéií]
@#
i)1`(#|@)\w+\1

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Outputs an inverted result, i.e. 0 for valid, 1 for invalid. Explanation:
i)`

Run the whole script case-insensitively.
ae|[aáoóuú]
#@

Mark broad vowels with #@.
[eéií]
@#

Mark slender vowels with @#.
1`(#|@)\w+\1

Check for consonants surrounded by vowels of different types (which equates to having surrounding symbols of the same type).
Note that Retina defaults to the ISO-8859-1 code page so all of the Irish vowels only cost one byte.

Haskell + hgl, 78 60 51 bytes
(ma.*pPX"[ei][^aeiou]+[aou]"~<rv)<rmD<<skX"ae_"<mtL

Attempt This Online!
Explanation
This works by making some reductions on the input and then running a simple regex on both the string and its reverse.

mtL convert to lower case.
skX"ae_" replace ae with a.
rmD remove the síntí fada.
~<rv on both the string and reverse ...
pPX"[ei][^aeiou]+[aou]" check if the pattern slender-cluster-broad occurs ...
ma get the logical or.

No regex, 69 bytes
(ma.*pP(ah'$xys"ei"<>so(nxy W5)<>xys"aou")~<rv)<rmD<<sk(ʃa<*ʃe)<mtL

Attempt This Online!
Reflection

There should be a version of gkY but for regexes.
There should be pPX but not for regexes. That is combine pP with ah'.
I could probably add a builtin for "aeiouáéíóú".
This regex reminds me of the regex used here. There might be a way to systematize this a bit to save bytes.
Just has xay has a string version there should be a string version of nxy.
Just as there are (<>?) and (?<>), there should be (<>*), (*<>), (<>+) and (+<>).
We could use some more versions of sY, or "split along". There's sYe to split along characters from a list of options, but it would be nice to have the opposite, to split along characters absent from a list. It would also be good to have variants for all of these that remove empty strings from the output, i.e. to split along clusters of matching characters.


05AB1E, 31 bytes
l„ae¬:žPS¡õKü2εεN<è"eiéí"så}Ë}P

Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
l            # Convert the (implicit) input-string to lowercase
 „ae         # Push string "ae"
    ¬        # Push its first character "a" (without popping)
     :       # Replace all "ae" with "a" in the lowercase input
žP           # Push the consonants constant "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"
  S¡         # Split the string on each consonant
    õK       # Remove all empty strings (where multiple adjacent consonants were)
ü2           # Pop and push all overlapping pairs
  ε          # Map over each pair:
   ε         #  Map over both vowel-strings in each pair:
    N        #   Push the 0-based index
     <       #   Decrease it by 1
      è      #   Use it to index into the vowel-string;
             #   N=0 → -1 → last character; N=1 → 0 → first character
    "eiéí"så #   Check if this character is one of "eiéí"
   }Ë        #  After the inner map: Check if both vowel-checks are the same;
             #  [1,1] for both slender; [0,0] for both broad; or 
             #  [0,1] or [1,0] for invalid
  }P         # After the outer map: Check if all are truthy
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)


Jelly, 30 bytes
Œlœṣ⁾aeKe€ØCœpƊO%65%9Ḃj€-FSƝ1e

A monadic Link that accepts a list of the specified characters and yields 0 for valid or 1 for invalid.
Try it online!
How?
Œlœṣ⁾aeKe€ØCœpƊO%65%9Ḃj€-FSƝ1e - Link: list of characters (limited to those specified)
Œl                             - convert to lowercase (works for fada e.g.: 'Ó' -> 'ó')
    ⁾ae                        - "ae"
  œṣ                           - split {Lowercased} at occurrences of {"ae"}
       K                       - join with spaces (we'll treat this as a wide vowel later)
              Ɗ                - last three links as a monad:
          ØC                   -   consonants -> "BCD...Zbcd...z"
         €                     -   for each {C in our string}:
        e                      -     {C} exists in {"BCD...Zbcd...z"}?
            œp                 -   partition {our string} at truthy indices of {that}
                                   discarding the borders
               O               - cast to ordinals
                %65            - mod 65
                   %9          - mod 9
                     Ḃ         - mod 2
                      j€-      - join each with -1
                         F     - flatten
                           Ɲ   - for neighbouring pairs:
                          S    -   sum
                            1e - contains 1?


Perl -Mutf8 -MUnicode::Normalize, 72 bytes
Thanks @bb94!
sub{s/ae/a/ig;$_=NFD$_;s/\pM//ug;($_.z.reverse)=~/[ei][^aeiouz]+[aou]/i}

Attempt This Online!
Perl -Mutf8 -MUnicode::Normalize, 75 bytes
Inverted truthy and falsey.
sub{s/ae/a/ig;$_=NFD$_;s/\pM//ug;s/[^aeiou]+/_/gi;/[aou]_[ei]|[ei]_[aou]/i}

Attempt This Online!

Can I remove NFD part so I could let the user apply such function as prerequisite?

Sorry if it wasn’t clear; you should assume that the input is in NFC.

72 bytes: sub{s/ae/a/ig;$_=NFD$_;s/\pM//ug;($_.z.reverse)=~/[ei][^aeiouz]+[aou]/i}

Raku (Perl 6) (rakudo), 56 55 bytes
{s:g:i/ae/a/;$_|.flip!~~m:i:m/[e|i]<-[aeiou]>+<[aou]>/}

Attempt This Online!
Explanation
The string-and-reverse trick was inspired by Wheat Wizard’s Haskell + hgl answer.
{s:g:i/ae/a/;$_|.flip!~~m:i:m/[e|i]<-[aeiou]>+<[aou]>/}­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
 s:g:i/ae/a/;                                            # ‎⁡Replace all instances of `ae` with `a` in the input (case-insensitively)
             $_|.flip!~~                                 # ‎⁢Does neither that string nor its reverse match...
                        m:i:m/[e|i]<-[aeiou]>+<[aou]>/   # ‎⁣the regex /[ei][^aeiou]+[aou]/ (case- and diacritic-insensitively)?


Created with the help of Luminespire.

Charcoal, 54 bytes
¹ＦＥＥ⪫⪪Ｓae¦a℅﹪℅↧ι¹³²⁻№]aouvι№eiι«Ｆ∧ι∧№υ⁰№υ±ι⎚Ｆ↔ι≔⟦⟧υ⊞υι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. - for valid, nothing if not. Explanation:
¹

Assume the word is valid.
ＦＥＥ⪫⪪Ｓae¦a℅﹪℅↧ι¹³²⁻№]aouvι№eiι«

Replace ae in the input with a, then for each letter, lowercase it, then reduce its ordinal modulo 132, which converts á to ], ú to v (which fortunately isn't a valid input) and the other accented letters to their base letter, then finally determine whether it's a broad vowel (mapped to 1), a slender vowel (mapped to -1) or a consonant (mapped to 0). Loop over the resulting list of letter types.
Ｆ∧ι∧№υ⁰№υ±ι⎚

If this is a vowel, the previous vowel was the other type of vowel, and there was an intervening consonant, then clear the canvas, marking the word as invalid.
Ｆ↔ι≔⟦⟧υ

If this is a vowel then clear any saved letter types.
⊞υι

Save the type of this letter.
